# What is unnormalised discrete distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Can someone provide an easy to understand meaning of what unnormalized discrete distribution is and how is it different from normalized discrete distribution and when is unnormalized discrete distribution used?

Comment: My guess is when $X$ is allowed to take the values $\infty, -\infty$ along with a countable number of real values $x_1,x_2,...$ and $p_n=P(X=x_n)%$ then $(p_n)$ is an unnormalized discrete distribution. Note that $p_n \geq 0$ and $\sum p_n \leq 1$ but strict inequality can occur.

Comment: What would then unnormalized mean?

Comment: Normalized means $\sum p_n=1$ and unnormalized means $\sum p_n<1$. But this is only  a guess. I have not seen anyone using this terminology.

Comment: Where did you encounter this "unnormalised discrete distribution"? Please provide the source.

Comment: It was a test task that was given to me in an interview